# Cannot collect kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My code always exit when executing this line, actually i already use coroutine to execute the collector code, and already use updated library for coroutine also

```
viewModel.rtList.collect{ list ->
    adapter.submitList(list)
}
```

and here is my full collector code

```
 viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "collect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                try {
                    viewModel.rtList.collect{ list ->
                        adapter.submitList(list)
                    }
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Log.e(TAG, "initObserver: ${e.message}", )
                }
                
            }
        }
```

And here is in ViewModel

````
 private var _rtList= MutableSharedFlow<List<DataRt>>()
 val rtList: SharedFlow<List<DataRt>> = _rtList

 fun getRtList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val list = mutableListOf<DataRt>()
            for (rt in 1..12){
                val dataRt = DataRt(rt.toString(),"0")
                list.add(dataRt)
            }
            _rtList.emit(list)
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "exit when executing this line"? Is it crashing? Are there any logs in the Logcat? Do you call somewhere `viewModel.getRtList()`?

Comment: there is no error inside log, i mean will return when reach this line 
viewModel.rtList.collect{ list ->

and won't to execute adapter.submitList(list)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you start collecting the data before it has been emitted. For example call `viewModel.getRtList()` after launching a coroutine to collect the data:

```
viewModel.rtList.collect { list ->
    adapter.submitList(list)
} 

viewModel.getRtList()
```

---

Or in this case it would be better to use a `flow{}` builder to execute a block of code each time the `Flow` is being collected:

`ViewModel`:

```
fun getRtList() = flow {
    val list = mutableListOf<DataRt>()
    for (rt in 1..12){
        val dataRt = DataRt(rt.toString(),"0")
        list.add(dataRt)
    }
    emit(list)
}
```

`Activity/Fragment`:

```
viewModel.getRtList().collect{ list ->
    adapter.submitList(list)
}
```

---

Or event better solution: don't use a `Flow` here, because you emit only one value and you don't call `suspend` functions:

`ViewModel`:

```
fun getRtList(): List<DataRt> {
    val list = mutableListOf<DataRt>()
    for (rt in 1..12){
        val dataRt = DataRt(rt.toString(),"0")
        list.add(dataRt)
    }
    return list
}
```

`Activity/Fragment`:

```
adapter.submitList(viewModel.getRtList())
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time.  Thanks.